# Query retorna true aunque se fuerce un false

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$id       = $_POST['id'];      //1
$sku      = $_POST['sku'];     //108872
$producto = $_POST['producto'];//SCANNER ONE 7800NX USB / SERIAL
$stock    = $_POST['stock'];   //196

$update = "  UPDATE productos
             SET sku     = '" . $sku . "',
                 producto='" . $producto . "',
                 stock   ='" . $stock . "'
             WHERE id ='".19."'"; <-- forzando el error acá
echo  $update."<br>"; // UPDATE productos SET sku = '108872', producto='SCANNER ONE 7800NX USB / SERIAL', stock ='196' WHERE id =19
$results = mysqli_query($link, $update);
echo var_dump($results); // bool(true)
exit;
```

Pero por alguna razón, el var_dump me retorna true, siendo que no hay registro 19 en la BBDD.
Por que me está tomando como true el update ???
Incluso al ejecutarlo en la base de datos, me da true.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que el id = 19 no exista en la base de datos no representa un error.

Comment: El update se ejecutó, sólo no encontró coincidencias. Puedes contar la cantidad de registros afectados con `mysqli_affected_rows($link)` si es igual a cero, lanzar una advertencia al usuario.

Comment: El tema, es que si hago eso y lo evalúo como affected_rows, si hago un update sin realizar cambios, tira error.

Comment: Es como dice @Blasito, la forma adecuada para saber si un UPDATE o un INSERT ocurrieron realmente, es verificando la filas afectadas, no verificando si se encontraron filas que cumplan el criterio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te retorna un `true` porque esa función solo te avisa si se llevó a cabo la ejecución de la consulta o no, solo te retornará `false` cuando encuentre un error de sintaxis o algo parecido.

Lo que podrías hacer para verificar si realizó una actualización o no, es usar el método `mysql_affected_rows()` inmediatamente después de ejecutar la consulta.

Te dejo un enlace para que te puedas guiar:
https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/mysqli_affected_rows.php

Comment: Lo intente pero si ejecuto el update sin cambiar nada, arroja error.

Comment: Terminé de corregirlo como se sugirió, revise el contenido generando un SELECT previamente, y luego analizando las affected_rows del select, para proceder con el UPDATE. Gracias !!

Answer (score 0):

Te está devolviendo *true* porque la sentencia *update* se lleva a cabo.

Estás intentando hacer un *update* y aunque no se encuentre dicho registro, la sentencia no da ningún fallo y devuelve todo ok, 0 filas afectadas, 0 warnings, por lo que devuelve true.

Si quieres establecer un control sobre esto deberías hacer un select previo para conocer si existe o no algún registro con id X.

Comment: Entonces, como contengo el error ??? por que no debería actualizar un registro que no existe... no recuerdo haberme topado con un update que se ejecute en un registro que no existe hasta ahora.

Comment: no se actualiza ningún registro. Una cosa es que la sentencia vaya bien o mal y otra diferente es que, una vez ha ido bien, actualice o no registros.

Es que los updates no se ejecutan sobre registros que existan o no. Se ejecuta una sentencia en la DB. Esta sentencia devuelve un objeto con información, entre la cual figura si la sentencia ha podido ser ejecuta con exito o no. La sentencia se ha podido ejecutar pero no ha afectado a ninguna fila.

Comment: Es como si tu escribes en DB:

UPDATE users SET name = 'AAAAAAAA' WHERE nombre = 'BBBBBBB';

Verás que la sentencia se te ejecua correctamente pero nadie pasa a llamarse *AAAAAAAA* porque no había nadie que se llamase *BBBBBBB*

Comment: Y como podría contener el error entonces ?? arriba me dijeron que evaluara con affected_rows, pero si hago el update sin cambios, tira error.

Comment: ¿qué error te tira?

Comment: Si hago el update si cambiar nada, da error

Comment: ¿qué error? no cuesta mucho copiar pegar el error.

Comment: Lo que te comenta @track3r es importante. Si no nos das información se hace muy difícil poder ayudar a resolver ningún problema.

Comment: @track3r Si haces update sin generar cambios, el proceso termina en error, dado que no hay filas afectadas en un update con los mismos datos.

Comment: @cooper Si alguien no responde, es por algo... si alguien ya comentó lo que tu estás repitiendo, solo queda esperar, sino la respuesta se cerrará. Paciencia amigo.

Comment: Sigues sin decirnos el error, no es lo mismo decir que termina en error que mostrar el error. Por favor, copia y pega el error que te sale cuando no hay filas.